# Does there exist a function $f$ analytic in the unit disc $\mathbb{D} := \{z ∈ \mathbb{C} | |z| < 1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is a past qual problem I am having trouble with.

Does there exist a function $f$ analytic in the unit disc $\mathbb{D} := \{z ∈ \mathbb{C} | |z| < 1\}$ such that for any $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$
$f(\frac{1}{n})·f(\frac{1}{n+1})=\frac{1}{n}$?

Using identity principle you get $f(z)f(\frac{z}{z + 1}) = z$ on the restriction to $0.5\mathbb{D}$.  I tried using maximum modulus principle without much luck. It is clear $f(\frac{1}{n}) > f(\frac{1}{n+2})$ and in general $f(x) > f(y)$, $x > y$ I think.  But this doesn't seem relevant.  It does give the following, $f(1)f(1/2) = 1$.  There for $f(x) < 1$ for $x \leq 1/2$.  Any thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you use identity principle at the beginning of last paragraph?

Comment: Define $g(z) = f(z)f(\frac{z}{z + 1}) = z$.  This makes sense on $0.5\mathbb{D}$ since then $|\frac{z}{1 + z}| < 1$.  Now $g(z) = z$ on $\{0\}\cup\{1/2, 1/3, 1/4...\}$  This sequence approaches its limit point $0$ so one version of the identity principle says we are good.

Comment: Ah, that's good. Though it makes the solution a bit longer than it needs to be. The size comparison   (as at the end of T. Bongers' answer) is the quickest way to the result: first notice $f(0)=0$, then conclude $f(1/n) f(1/(n+1)) = O(1/n^2)$, contradicting the assumption. This, incidentally, works for real-differentiable functions too, which don't have an identity principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even easier, differentiate your functional equation, obtaining
$$f'(z)f\left(\frac z{z+1}\right) + f(z)f'\left(\frac z{z+1}\right)\cdot\frac1{(z+1)^2} = 1.$$
Since $f(0)=0$, evaluating at $z=0$ yields $0=1$.

Comment: That's rather pretty.

Comment: Thanks @T.Bongers. I thought of it as you were entering your solution, also motivated by the intuition that $(f(z))^2\sim z$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that such an $f$ exists; letting $n \to \infty$ in the given identity, we get

$$f(0)^2 = 0 \implies f(0) = 0$$

This motivates setting

$$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z}$$

so that $g$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$, given $g(0)$ defined appropriately. Then $g$ satisfies the identity

$$g\left(\frac 1 n\right) = \frac{f(1/n)}{1/n} = \frac{f(1/n)}{f(1/n) f(1/(n + 1))} = \frac{1}{f(1/(n + 1))}$$

But the right-side is unbounded as $n$ grows, since $f(0) = 0$. This contradicts that $g$ is analytic at $0$.

---

So in the end, this is true because $f$ tends to zero at the same rate as $\sqrt x$ does, but it can't - it has to approach zero at *least* linearly.